# Unable to issue the statement CREATE ROLE failed for 'application_rw'@'%'. ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE ROLE failed for 'application_rw'@'%'

Tags: sql, mysql, database, database-administration

I have a small problem in MySQL.
When I try to create a **role** with this syntax:

```
CREATE ROLE 'application_rw'@'%';
```

It does not work.
However, when I try with the following syntax:

```
CREATE ROLE 'application_rw'@'localhost';
```

that works.

I feel like when installing and configuring MySQL, I chose an option that restricted me to only placing commands at the localhost level.

How can I change this?